# Wired Connection Suddenly stopped working on ubuntu 12.04 after update

Tags: internet, ubuntu-12.04, ethernet, wired-networking

Here is the thing! am on day 5 of no wired internet connection. I have spent the last 4 days searching through every forum and Q&A sites, until i finally decided to post this, so I have done my homework. Before I take my laptop to maintenance shop for hardware failures i want to check with you guys first.

**Problem Description:**
  Like the question says my wired connection stopped working suddenly after an update. I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Network Manager says **Wired Networks disconnected**. Wireless is working perfectly. And also it doesn't work on Windows 7 too, it says cable unplugged. I have tried the cable on other computer and it works perfectly.

**nm-tool output:**

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [Connectify-me] -----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        9C:4E:36:29:F7:D4

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           58 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    TP-LINK_8AB114:  Infra, A0:F3:C1:8A:B1:14, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA2
    ZTE_HG_0:        Infra, 00:1D:0F:BF:BE:61, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 47
    ZTE_HG_0:        Infra, 00:21:27:C1:19:D9, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39
    *Connectify-me:  Infra, E8:39:DF:3E:AF:8E, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 87 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.241.104
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.241.1

    DNS:             192.168.241.1


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:1E:DE:F7:A6:C9

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

**sudo lshw -C network** *output:*

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c1
       serial: 00:1e:de:f7:a6:c9
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 9c:4e:36:29:f7:d4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-57-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.241.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
resources: irq:46 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

**ifconfig eth0** *output:*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:de:f7:a6:c9  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:48
```

So there you have it guys! Let me know if you need additional information. So Please help me!!!

Comment: It is probably a driver problem. Can you please post the output of lspci -vnn | grep -i net

Comment: 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet [1969:2062] (rev c1)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0890] (rev c4)

Comment: @MariusMatutiae..i have also downloaded compat wireless and loaded the module atl1c, but still no luck.

Comment: Try mii-tool -r, pls

Comment: when i tried that without sudo i get `SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth1' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth2' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth3' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth4' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth5' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth6' failed: Operation not permitted
SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth7' failed: Operation not permitted
no MII interfaces found
`When i use sudo i get `restarting autonegotiation...
`

Comment: And does it work? I take it it does not... (sudo is required)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae...don't give up on me man.

Comment: Ok, but after lunch and class, sorry

Comment: Please post output of sudo ethtool eth0; if you don0t have ethtool, sudo apt-get install ethtool.

Comment: `Settings for eth0:
 Supported ports: [ TP ]
 Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
 Supported pause frame use: No
 Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
 Advertised link modes:  Not reported
 Advertised pause frame use: No
 Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
 Speed: Unknown!
 Duplex: Unknown! (255)
 Port: Twisted Pair
 PHYAD: 0
 Transceiver: internal
 Auto-negotiation: on
 MDI-X: Unknown
 Supports Wake-on: pg
 Wake-on: d
 Current message level: 0x0000003f (63)
          drv probe link timer ifdown ifup
 Link detected: no`

Comment: The last line here says: *Link detected:no*. So either it is not a software problem, or  if it is, it is at the kernel level, which is way outside my horizon. You may try checking the cable, but apart from this I am at my wit's end. Sorry.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae...Thank you for trying...I guess am gonna have to take it to the maintenance shop.

Answer (score 4):

Yours is not a clear-cut situation, so we go by successive approximations.

First, issue these commands:

```
    sudo service network-manager stop
    sudo ifconfig eth0 down
    sudo ifconfig eth0 up
    sudo dhclient eth0
```

and see whether this works. In any case, re-issue

```
    sudo service network-manager start
```

Second. We may try to install the latest atl1c driver. Go to a convenient, empty directory, and issue these commands:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
    wget http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless.tar.bz2
    tar xvf compat-wireless.tar.bz2
    cd compat-wireless-2012-12-18/
    scripts/driver-select atl1c
    make
    sudo make install
    sudo rmmod atl1c 
    sudo modprobe atl1c
    sudo ifconfig eth0 down
    sudo ifconfig eth0 up
    sudo dhclient eth0
```

and see now whether this works. Just let me know, if at all solvable your problem will require a few iterations.

Comment: All of the above didn't solve the problem. `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and   `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` didn't give any response` but `sudo dhclient eth0` stays on the prompt without any response, it doesn't close. The output of `sudo make install` this might be helpful make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic'
  INSTALL /home/take/trouble/compat-wireless-2012-12-18/compat/compat.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/take/trouble/compat-wireless-2012-12-18/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1c/atl1c.ko
Can't read private key
  DEPMOD  3.8.0-34-generic

Comment: Can't read private key does not mean anything, just plunge ahead. But did you stop network manager before trying the first method? It is important.

Comment: yes i did. It stopped my wifi connection too. I re enabled it to post here.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a problem like this with an old desktop. I spent a couple of days trying to work out what happened. I reloaded the machine several times. Checked all lshw, lspci, ifconfig etc etc. Nothing worked. I even unplugged it and plugged it back in - nothing! The second time I pulled the plug on it - just as I went to plug it back in I noticed that the LED on the PSU did not go fully out.

I then pulled the power cable and left it out until the PSU LED went out - took about 15 seconds.

That resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found that no amount of drivers, bios, or uninstall/reinstalls worked.

Can you try opening your computer case/laptop and resetting the CMOS by

1. removing/installing battery
2. simply moving the jumpers from position 1-2 to 2-3, then waiting about 10 seconds, then reverting back to their default 1-2 spot?

The only way I was able to solve this was the CMOS method, as it appears as though my computer might have been subject to some kind of power surge or failure (even though everything was on surge protectors).

On a side note I probably need to get better surge protectors.

Answer (score -1):

Wired properties carrier is off; must activate it:

```
echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer little bit more?